# My application is having trouble on real devices

Tags: android

I have finish my application and run it perfectly on my emulator (*Nexus 6 API 22*). But when I try to run it on a real device, I have troubles, in the first device (*with version 5*) I have tried crash when I start an activity that implements google maps. At first I try to solve it by set it my key to the release folder as well as on the debug one, but the keep crashing. I thought was about some permissions or dependencies, but I thing I have everything right.

**My build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jocadoci.soloordena"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
     compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
     compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

**And the AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jocadoci.soloordena">

<uses-permission
    android:name="jocadoci.soloordena.android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="mypackage.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/soloorndenalogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">


    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MapsItaly"/>
    <activity android:name=".ListViewCheckboxesActivity"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".DrawerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Then I try on another device (*this one was with version 4.2.2*), in this device just doesn't want to start, crashed when you tried to open it. I tried to change the version on my compileSDKVersion between 24 and 25 but look that is not that the problem. At this moment I don't know what else do, I thought also that was because my application use a google service should be post it already on google play, I did it but also did not work. 
I will appreciate anyone who could help me.
Thanks in advance.

**P.S**: If someone want to try the app is in the store already but looks that only is available in Mexico, but if some one want to try it I could send my app-release.apk

**UPDATE**

First thanks all of you for give the time to answer. I appreciate.

Thanks to @Windsor answer came to me the doubt about using the same API key for the debug and release file. Looking about my sha-1 key and on the google development website I realize that indeed I could use the same API key for both files (debug and release) but the think was that with the generated signed key that I create building my apk I could use the sha-1 to add one more restriction to my API key and could use it to the app-release.apk. Successful the app run correctly on a real device (version 5), but unfortunately keep stopped on others version devices.

Comment: When app is crashing you will get an error log, usually with a stack trace and a message describing a problem. No one can help you if you will not post it. You can even help yourself when reading it.

Comment: Just say that my application has stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello can you cheked Location Permision for API level 23?

Comment: What do you mean sorry?

Comment: Check Permission for API Level 23

Comment: I hope this one help for you

Comment: Thanks sir, this help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate a signed apk.

Make sure you have your sha1 release key on Google API services. Does debug work on real devices?

Can't tell you without seeing the main activity.

If you api key isn't working normally you just don't get a map. If it works on multiple android versions in a emulator ods are api key. Debug keys don't work in the final copy you need to generate a apk with the release key!!!

Could be you method for getting location services.

I build for the lowest target version test then add compatibility for newer version that's what I like.

Comment: If you don't have an answer don't give one.

Comment: Are you saying that I need another api key, not the one I was using before?